# Write ActiveX control in C# but use it in MFC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, mfc, activex

The current projects are all written in **VC6** and **VB6**. It has been proved that .Net can write Active X controls for MFC use. So we'd like to write some active x controls using .Net with minimum changes in the legacy code.

Here is the **requirements**:

1. The Host application (written in VC6) must be able to find and load the active x control from the registered category.
2. The active x control must support property pages.
3. The active x control must support property persistence.

Here is my **questions**:

1. Is it possible to write Active X property pages using .Net WinForm Controls? And how to communicate between controls and corresponding properties in C#?
2. How to register the Active X control under a certain category in C#? The following is a piece of sample code in MFC regarding to control registration.

   ```
   STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
   {

   HRESULT hr;  

   AFX_MANAGE_STATE(_afxModuleAddrThis);

   if (!AfxOleRegisterTypeLib(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), _tlid))
     return ResultFromScode(SELFREG_E_TYPELIB);

   if (!COleObjectFactoryEx::UpdateRegistryAll(TRUE))
     return ResultFromScode(SELFREG_E_CLASS); 

   hr = CreateComponentCategory(CATID_CTRL_CAT, 
        L"XXXX");
   if (FAILED(hr))
     return hr;

   hr = RegisterCLSIDInCategory(CATID_CONTROL, 
        CATID_CTRL_CAT);
   if (FAILED(hr))
       return hr; 

   return NOERROR;
   }
   ```

   The above registration has 3 steps, **AfxOleRegisterTypeLib**, **CreateComponentCategory** and **RegisterCLSIDInCategory**. How can we implement them in C#?
3. What is the equivalent way in C# to achieve property persistence?

Thank you in advance for any comments and helps!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write a .NET ActiveX component to be consumed by a legacy application, and I initially explored implementing this in C#.  While it's not terribly difficult to implement a component in C# that provides the bare minimum to satisfy the modern definition of "ActiveX component" (i.e. implement the COM IUnknown interface), building a component in C# that supports all of the drag-and-drop ease of use that was expected by the legacy application developers consuming my component required that it implement many additional COM interfaces.

My understanding is that it's technically possible to do this yourself in C#, provided that you import the right COM interfaces and then implement them properly within your component, this would be a lot of work.

I ended up creating a normal C# component (no ActiveX involved) to contain all of my actual logic, and then I created a C++/CLI (A.K.A. Managed C++) wrapper around my C# component that used MFC to provide the necessary ActiveX functionality.

Disclaimer: I did not have to deal with property pages or property persistence.

Comment: This gives me another idea that mix MFC and managed C++ code might meet my requirements. Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Mix MFC and managed C++ will be my desired approach for now as it is obviously much easier to for me, although the host application has to be re-compiled with clr support. Thanks again.

Comment: @james - I'm glad that this direction looks viable for your situation.  You said, "the host application has to be re-compiled with clr support"; I'm not sure if I understand that. In my case, I made an MFC ActiveX project in my solution, which contained my ActiveX wrapper for my .NET components, so that project did need to be compiled with CLR support. The host application (the GUI application consuming the ActiveX control) doesn't need to be aware of .NET, though.

Comment: Hi @Dr. Wily's Apprentice, this is another question I'd like to ask actually. I couldn't run the host program if my activex control uses any winform control. But if I remove the winform control everything works just fine. All I add is just a Static mfc control but associate it with MaskedTextBox variable and do a managed data exchange, that's it. That's why I think I have to re-compile the host program to make it work...but I don't have the host program to give a try...